# Is it possible to create ByteBuffer from a List<ByteBuffer>?

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

Let's say i have a list/arrayList or an array of ByteBuffers (`List<ByteBuffer>` or `ByteBuffer[]`)

It is possible from this to directly get the bytes from the above array without iterating through all the items or computing their total size? I am looking for something like this:

```
ByteBuffer[] bufferList = new ByteBuffer[7]; //this can be any kind of list of ByteBuffers
//add items to the array
ByteBuffer buffer = (ByteBuffer) bufferList; //what i want to achieve
```

Of course the last line is not correct.

The thing is that i already have in the array all the bytes in order, but I want them not to be in a list anymore, but in a single ByteBuffer. So is there something that makes possible to create a ByteBuffer from a list/array of ByteBuffers?

Thank you!

Comment: You have individual `ByteBuffer` elements in an array or list that each have X bytes and you want to add all those bytes to a single `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: You're likely going to just have to write a method for it.

Comment: Make a new ByteBuffer, iterate through your array of buffers, get each bytebuffer as an array using .array(), and use put(byte[]) into your new ByteBuffer

Comment: Yes @SotiriosDelimanolis. I have a list of ByteBuffers that have different byte size and i want to create a single ByteBuffer from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public ByteBuffer convertToOne(ByteBuffer[] src)
{
    int size=0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < src.length ; i++) {
        size+=src[i].array().length;
    }

    ByteBuffer newBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

    int sizeAt = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < src.length ; i++) {
        newBuffer.put(src[i].array(), sizeAt);
        sizeAt += src[i].array().length;
    }
    return newBuffer;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this solution would be that i have to make another iteration to compute the elements total bytes size. (The ByteBuffer items don't have constant size) So the problem would be how i initialize the final ByteBuffer (the newBuffer in this case).

Comment: How do you initialize the original buffer? I'm assuming you have a concrete class somehwere.

Comment: then how do i create 'ByteBuffer dest' ? Don't i have to allocate the size before putting things into it?

Comment: Where did your array of ByteBuffers come from. The class is abstract, if you have instances of them then you have a concrete class somewhere

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I use this ByteBuffer implementation: [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) So i cannot simply instantiate it.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to need to compute the size

Comment: i want to avoid this... :(

Comment: There's no way around it. If java had a method to do this, it would be implemented by doing that anyway. Native java methods aren't magic.

Comment: I know i can transform the List<ByteBuffer> to byte[] and then this to put it very simple in the ByteBuffer. I think this way the complexity is lower... But still.. i am hoping that i am missing something and there can be a better option to this

Comment: There is only one way to create a ByteBuffer, by specifying size. Also, there are no ByteBuffer methods which return a ByteBuffer of a different size. It therefore then follows that you need to compute size first.

Comment: If you have some size which you know all of the buffers cannot exceed some max buffer size, you could use that as your size. That's generally how buffers should be picked anyway. If your array of buffers total is bigger than your max buffer size, then your buffer is too big anyway, and you can catch that exception in this method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to have to create a new `ByteBuffer` and copy each of the buffers in `bufferList` into the new one. You should put this functionality in a method so as to not repeat the code each time you use it.

Comment: Yes. I know i can do this. but this will require to iterate through all the ByteBuffers to compute their total size, then create the big ByteBuffer, and the interate again to add them. I was looking for something more optimum, if it is possible.

Comment: Iterating over the collection is going to take a fraction of the time that creating the big ByteBuffer and copying the other ByteBuffers is going to take. Any built-in function is most likely going to do this anyway.

Comment: the issue is.. that i am trying to create a serializer, so in the end I need a single ByteBuffer not a list of ByteBuffers. That is why i want to transform a list of BB to a single BB